# ¿Cómo puedo cargar o abrir un proyecto de C# en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

estoy tratando de editar un programa ya creado en c sharp pero no se como cargarlo en windows form . https://platea21.blogspot.mx/2016/12/sistema-de-reserva-y-facturacion-hoteles.html

Comment: ¿Qué IDE estás utilizando?

Comment: visual studio 2013

Comment: Por lo general, todo los IDEs tienen las mismas opciones de abrir un proyecto. Quizás sería bueno que mires [Importar un Proyecto Terminado A Visual Estudio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UK1ClxTpv9c).

Comment: gracias lo checare.

Answer (score 1):

Busca el archivo .sln, por lo que puedo ver en la solución que descargaste, necesitas abrir **HBRS.sln**.

Simplemente con hacerle doble click te abrirá Visual Studio listo para que compiles y comiences a modificar.o.